# Does the medic remove cubes of the final cured disease (and thus eradicate it) before the game ends in a win?

Tags: pandemic

Consider a scenario in which your group is doing absurdly well. Three diseases have been eradicated, and while the fourth disease — Red — has not yet been cured, it has been contained to a single city, in which the Medic is already present.

Then it happens. The Operations Expert, holding three red cards, moves to a Research Center where the Researcher, holding two red cards, is already present. The Operations Expert takes those two red cards and then cures the final disease. You've won!

But since the Medic is in the only city still infected by the (now cured) Red Fever, that one is instantly treated as well.

Have you now won with full eradication? Or did the game already end once the fourth disease was cured?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, according to Matt Leacock (one of the game's designers) on a [BGG thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/21295531#21295531) for Pandemic Legacy Season 1, the disease is eradicated. The medic's ability is immediate, so the cubes are cured and the disease eradicated. Pandemic Legacy Season 1 has rules very similar to those of Pandemic, so I wouldn't hesitate applying this ruling to the regular Pandemic.

Note that in Legacy, unlike vanilla Pandemic, eradicating a disease has consequences in terms of game-end upgrades, so the timing of things is quite important.

Answer (score 0):

See the last page of the rules, it says

> If a disease has been cured, he automatically removes all cubes of that color from a city, simply by entering it or being there. This does not take an action.

the page before says

> The players win as soon as cures to all 4 diseases are discovered.

Link to the rules from the publishers website: https://images.zmangames.com/filer_public/e6/75/e6757883-0976-467a-85f3-c383f1bae17c/zm7101_rules_2018_web.pdf

Comment: While this is useful in most cases this does not answer the question if the game ends as soon as the final cure happens or if the medics ability still has time to eradicate the final disease. The question even mentions this ability to treat the disease in the area around the medic just by being there.

Comment: as a not-english-native-speaker I assumed it means "if the disease are cured (done cured: "check win: checked. won! games ends") - than afterwards - the medic removes the cubes ( but here not needed anymore, already won)" ... but this is not my native language, so maybe somebody else who can read between the lines in his own language can give this assumptions more ground. Also the rulebook says "The players win as soon as cures to all 4 diseases are discovered.", ill update my answer to include it.

Comment: What you have there is correct but the question is what happens first. Does the medic remove the cubes and the disease get eradicated? Or does the game end? While you are correct in stating that the game is won either way there is a difference in winning with all diseases eradicated and winning with 3.

Comment: "As soon" seems to happen faster than "automatic", at least in my limited understanding - but lets leave it to the philologists ... maybe a good question for english.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I am guessing that question about the wording is why the question was asked and why the game designer clarified it on board game geek.